# Can I apply both winsorization and CUPED to my experiment results?

Tags: variance, experiment-design, ab-test, winsorizing

Our current experimentation platform currently has winsorization implemented to reduce "whale effects" on metrics like revenue and volume. We are also interested in applying CUPED to further reduce variances based on pre-experiment values.

My question is: can I apply both and in what way would make the most sense?

My analysis shows CUPED does indeed reduce the variances for revenue when compared to the non-winsorized values but they're still larger when compared to the winsorized variances.

Comment: Can you please explain CUPED?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure - CUPED is a variance reduction technique. It stands for "Controlled-experiment Using Pre-Existing Data" and uses pre-experiment data to control for natural variation in an experiment’s north star metric. By removing natural variation, we can run statistical tests that require a smaller sample size. Often times the covariate chosen is the north star metrics pre-experiment data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply both.
First,apply winsorizing on pre-experiment data and post-experiment data.
Second,use the winsorized pre-experiment data and winsorized post-experiment data to calculate theta of CUPED.
If you do this you will have a lower variance than the the winsorized variances